# Parse multilevel json into a csv using jq tool in unix

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I have a multilevel json like so:

```
{
    "id": "id123",
    "details": {
        "prod": "prod123",
        "etype": "type1"
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
            "bankName": "bank123",
            "accountType": "account123",
            "openingBalance": "bal123",
            "fromDate": "2023-01-01",
            "toDate": "2023-01-01",
            "missingMonths": [],
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "dateTime": "2020-12-01",
                    "description": "a very long string",
                    "amount": -599.0,
                    "bal": 8154.83,
                    "type": "Debit"
                },
                {
                    "dateTime": "2020-12-01",
                    "description": "a very long string; a very long string",
                    "amount": -4000.0,
                    "balanceAfterTransaction": 4154.83,
                    "type": "Debit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "accountid": "sample123"
}
```

I want to parse it to a csv in the following format:

```
id,prod,etype,bankName,accountType,openingBalance,fromDate,toDate,dateTime,description,amount,bal,type,accountid
id123,prod123,type1,bank123,account123,bal123,2023-01-01,2023-01-01,2020-12-01,a very long string,-599.0,8154.83,Debit,sample123
id123,prod123,type1,bank123,account123,bal123,2023-01-01,2023-01-01,2020-12-01,a very long string; a very long string,-4000.0,4157.83,Debit,sample123
```

Parse the transactions into a proper csv and repeat the common info for each transaction.

I have gotten only so far yet:

`jq --raw-output '[ .id, .details[], .accounts[].transactions[] ]'`

Answer (score 1):

This will help you get the desired CSV format:

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.id),\(.details.prod),\(.details.etype),\(.accounts[].bankName)"'
```

you can build further on it to get all desired values..

Note: For a valid CSV though, you might need to add double-quotes around some values, like strings

to parse multiple JSON entries, they are expected to be in an array:

```json
[
{
    "id": "id123",
    "details": {
        "prod": "prod123",
        "etype": "type1"
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
.....
        }
     ]
},
{
    "id": "id124",
    "details": {
        "prod": "prod124",
        "etype": "type1"
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
.....
        }
     ]
}
]
```

Comment: i don't think it will repeat the common elements for multiple transactions

Comment: Answer Updated.

Comment: For robustness, if you want CSV, it would be best to use jq's `@csv` filter

Answer (score 1):

You can save the outer data values in variables and get down progressively to the leaf nodes :

```
jq -r '"id,prod,etype,bankName,accountType,openingBalance,fromDate,toDate,dateTime,description,amount,bal,type,accountid",
    ( . as {$id,$accountid}
    | .details as {$prod, $etype}
    | .accounts[]
    | . as { $bankName,$accountType,$openingBalance,$fromDate,$toDate }
    | .transactions[]
    | [$id,$prod,$etype,$bankName,$accountType,$openingBalance,$fromDate,$toDate,.dateTime,.description,.amount,.bal? // .balanceAfterTransaction,.type,$accountid]
    | join(","))' input.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses jq's `@csv` filter for robustness, and avoids redundancy by using arrays of key names
that can also be used for generating the header row.  The fiddle with .bal uses jq's `//=` assignment operator in a way that avoids interfering with the main thrust of the program.

```
["id","prod","etype"] as $idHdrs
| ["bankName", "accountType", "openingBalance", "fromDate", "toDate"] as $accountHdrs
| ["dateTime", "description", "amount", "bal", "type"] as $txHdrs
| $idHdrs + $accountHdrs + $txHdrs + ["accountid"],   # the header row
  ( . as {$id,$accountid}
    | .details as {$prod, $etype}
    | .accounts[]
    | [.[$accountHdrs[]]] as $accounts
    | .transactions[]
    | .bal //= .balanceAfterTransaction  # fiddle
    | [.[$txHdrs[]]] as $transactions
    | [$id,$prod,$etype] + $accounts + $transactions + [$accountid] )
| @csv
```

Output:

```
"id","prod","etype","bankName","accountType","openingBalance","fromDate","toDate","dateTime","description","amount","bal","type","accountid"
"id123","prod123","type1","bank123","account123","bal123","2023-01-01","2023-01-01","2020-12-01","a very long string",-599,8154.83,"Debit","sample123"
"id123","prod123","type1","bank123","account123","bal123","2023-01-01","2023-01-01","2020-12-01","a very long string; a very long string",-4000,4154.83,"Debit","sample123"
```